# detect whether app is running on simulator or on device (as3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, simulator

i've found some solutions for this but no one for as3:

I'm developping an app for ios with AS3, and i'd like to set a variable that detects whether the app is running in the adl simulator or on the real device.

Is that possible with as3? i've searched on adobe doc, this forum and google, and found nothing.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I create a Boolean for debug and set it true when developing and false when will release

Comment: thanks, i've already made this one, but i thought there would be a way to do it automatically.this makes me think my last publication went wrong because i forgot to change this variable. thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

As for ADL simulator you can simply check the Capabilities.cpuArchitecture == "ARM" statement. For ADL is false, whilst for iOS sim and iOS or Android device it is true.